# is it possible to redirect console output to a variable?

Tags: r, console, sink

In R, I'm wondering if it's possible to temporarily redirect the output of the console to a variable?

p.s. There are a few examples on the web on how to use `sink()` to redirect the output into a filename, but none that I could find showing how to redirect into a variable.

p.p.s. The reason this is useful, in practice, is that I need to print out a portion of the default console output from some of the built-in functions in R.

Comment: You're far, far better off rewriting the functions rather than trying to parse the text they output.

Comment: @Ari B. Friedman Unfortunately, that's just not feasible. Currently, all I want to do is chop off some extra line feeds to squeeze the output down to a manageable length.

Comment: @Ben Bolker. Brilliant! This works beautifully. If you add it as an answer, I'll upvote it and mark it as the official answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe `results <- capture.output(...)` is what you need (i.e. using the default `file=NULL` argument).  `sink(textConnection("results")); ...; sink()` should work as well, but as `?capture.output` says, `capture.output()` is:

> Related to ‘sink’ in the same way that ‘with’ is related to ‘attach’.

... which suggests that `capture.output()` will generally be better since it is more contained (i.e. you don't have to remember to terminate the `sink()`).

If you want to send the output of multiple statements to a variable you can wrap them in curly brackets `{}`, but if the block is sufficiently complex it might be better to use `sink()` (or make your code more modular by wrapping it in functions).

Comment: Ben, two notes: 1) `results <- sink()` won't do anything - `sink()` always returns NULL. 2) I don't agree that `capture.output` is better than `sink` - on the contrary, because `sink` allows that the code is not a single function call. Please follow my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25781458/684229

Answer (score 20):

For the record, it's indeed possible to store `stdout` in a variable with the help of a temporary connection without calling `capture.output` -- e.g. when you want to save both the results and `stdout`. Example:

1. Prepare the variable for the diverted R output:

   ```
   > stdout <- vector('character')
   > con    <- textConnection('stdout', 'wr', local = TRUE)
   ```
2. Divert the output:

   ```
   > sink(con)
   ```
3. Do some stuff:

   ```
   > 1:10
   ```
4. End the diversion:

   ```
   > sink()
   ```
5. Close the temporary connection:

   ```
   > close(con)
   ```
6. Check results:

   ```
   > stdout
   [1] " [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10"
   ```

Comment: That was almost what I was looking for. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396806/convert-a-message-to-a-character-vector for how to capture messages while still saving the results

Comment: @Latrunculia for that goal, I suggest checking `pander::evals` eg at https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/pander/vignettes/evals.html

Comment: this worked for me to capture messages using sink(`type = "message")`. For some reason I couldn't get `capture.output()` to work.