# Convert a printed message into a character vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a file `"data.txt"`, which can be created with the following code

```
m <- matrix(c(13, 14, 4950, 20, 50, 4949, 22, 98, 4948, 
              30, 58, 4947, 43, 48, 4946), 5, byrow = TRUE)
write.table(m, "data.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Reading the file into R with `scan`, a message is delivered along with the data.

```
( s <- scan("data.txt") )
# Read 15 items
#  [1]   13   14 4950   20   50 4949   22   98 4948
# [10]   30   58 4947   43   48 4946
```

I'd like to retrieve the message `Read 15 items` as a character vector. I know I can get the last recorded warning by typing `last.warning`, and can turn it into a character vector with `names(last.warning)`, but there is no such object as `last.message`.

Is there a way to convert an outputted message to a character vector?  The desired result would be

```
[1] "Read 15 items"
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `length` afterwards?

Comment: My fault, I edited the question.  I'd like to know in general how to turn messages into character vectors

Comment: @RichardScriven As you probably know, `capture.output` or `sink` would normally do the trick. I don't quite understand why they don't work here.

Comment: sink doesn't work because message has a custom call to `cat` that specifies `file=stderr()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default hander for `message()` sends the result to `stderr` via `cat()`. You can capture that with

```
tc <- textConnection("messages","w")
sink(tc, type="message")
s <- scan("data.txt")
sink(NULL, type="message")
close(tc)

messages
# [1] "Read 5 items"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a convenient wrapper for `sink` in `utils::capture.output()`

```
z<-capture.output(s<-scan("data.txt"), type="message")
z
#> [1] "Read 15 items"
```