# Is there an R function that returns the console output as a string?

Tags: r, redcap

Long story short, I am trying to migrate a really large project from one REDCap server to another using an API through R.

I  won't go into details, but it is looking like I have to transfer the tabular data across cell by cell. By my calculations, due to the size of this project,  this code will have to run overnight.

I am wanting to know whether there is an R function that returns the console output so that I can see whether the data migration has been successful for each cell when I return to work in the morning.
Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358869/12957340 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/24397137/12957340

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a printed message into a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396806/convert-a-printed-message-into-a-character-vector)

Comment: @jared_mamrot thank you! That works - I had another question, does capture.output actually run the line of code?

Comment: yes, it does ....