# How to tee/split/copy console output into variable in R?

Tags: r

How can I sink the output of certain code into a variable? I want that output to still go to the console.

I much prefer the `sink` notation; I don't want to use `capture.output` for two reasons:

1. It requires the respective code to be a single function; I don't want to complicate my code by creating functions just to capture output
2. It doesn't allow the captured output to still go to console.

I came up with the code below, but it's a bit complicated. Is there an easier solution?

```
fileName <- tempfile()
sink(fileName, split = TRUE)
...
sink()
out <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
unlink(fileName)
```

Comment: Maybe make use of `%>%` (magrittr) or `%>>%` (pipeR) to copy the stuff being sent to console over to a subsequent `write` operation?   Or maybe this is your chance to publish a `%tee%` operator :-) before `magrittr` does. See http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: you should just use `futile.logger` it does everything plus extra

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't seem so bad, but you can streamline things a little bit by using a `textConnection`:

```
sink(tt <- textConnection("results","w"),split=TRUE)
print(11:15)
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15
sink()
results
## [1] "[1] 11 12 13 14 15"
close(tt) ## clean up
```

The only thing to watch out for is that if you don't close the connection, `results` will be have *locked bindings* (see `?textConnection`), which will mean that you can't e.g. assign a new value to it.

> The output character vector has locked bindings (see ‘lockBinding’) until ‘close’ is called on the connection.

Alternatively, you don't have to wrap multiple statements into a function to get them into `capture.output()` - you can use curly brackets `{}` to make multiple statements into a single evaluated output ...

```
results <- capture.output(split=TRUE,{
   print("hello")
   print("goodbye")
})
```