# How to store the console output to a variable in R

Tags: r, terminal, output

In R I would like to store a console command to a variable. I have already tried with the solutions proposed in the following link but without luck: [In R, is it possible to redirect console output to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358435/in-r-is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-variable)
Here you are the command I'm using:

```
test <- capture.output(system("pa11y scuolafalconeborsellino.it; 
        perl -e \"print unpack('c', pack('C', $?)), \\$/\""), file = NULL)
```

The output visiblein the console is:

> [4m[36m
>   Welcome to Pa11y[39m[24m
>   [90mWe'll sniff your page for you now.
>   [39m
>   [36m > [39mLoading page...
>   [36m > [39mRunning HTML CodeSniffer...
>   [36m > [39m[31mError: HTML CodeSniffer error[39m
>
> -1

but the variable test is empty.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`system` has a parameter `intern` which can be used to save the output to a character vector:

```
test <- system("pa11y scuolafalconeborsellino.it; perl -e \"print unpack('c', pack('C', $?)), \\$/\"", 
               intern = TRUE)
```

Note that `system2` is now prefered and `system` should be avoided in new code.

Comment: Could you provide a link regarding your last sentence? I am curious.

Comment: @Pascal See `help("system")`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `unix2dos` on Linux. `system("unix2dos ...", intern = TRUE)` returns `character(0)` and the output is still printed to the console.