# Capture the printed output from a function (but still return its value) in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to have output from a function that prints output *not* print to the console.

The `capture.output` function is recommended in [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358435/in-r-is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-variable), but it's not clear to me how to capture the output but still return the function's output.

E.g., if I have function `f()` and want `"printed output!"` to not print to the console but to have `"value"` be returned:

```r
f <- function() {
    print("printed output!")
    return("value")
}

# printed output is returned - want to capture the output

f()
#> [1] "printed output!"
#> [1] "value"

# also doesn't work, as captured output and function's output is returned

capture.output(f())
#> [1] "[1] \"printed output!\"" "[1] \"value\""
```

I think the solution may involve using [sink](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) (and `con()`), but the answer that uses them does not use a function (and so I'm having difficulty applying the approach).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assign the output of the function like this:

```
capture <- capture.output(result <- f()); result
## [1] "value"
```

Comment: You could also just wrap the whole thing in `invisible` instead of assigning to a value `invisible(capture.output(result <- f()))`

Comment: It might be useful to the questioner to explain that `<-` is a function that returns the value of its RHS as well as effecting an assignment to a symbol.

Comment: @42- I think that makes sense