# In fable's ARIMA function, is it possible to capture the output from trace = TRUE?

Tags: r, arima, fable-r

In `fable`'s `ARIMA` function, we have the option to see all models that are evaluated with the `trace = TRUE` option. (Example below.) This output just prints to the console.

Is there any place that this model evaluation history is getting saved or is there any way to save the printed console output?

```
library(dplyr)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)

df <- aus_livestock |> 
    filter(Animal == 'Pigs', State == 'Queensland')

fcst <- df |>
    model(arima = ARIMA(Count, trace = TRUE))

# Prints all models tried, but only saves final selected model:
# Model specification       Selection metric
# ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,0,1)[12]+c Inf
# ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[12]+c 21811.280078
# ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[12]+c 21524.227259
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[12]+c 21470.955343
# Search iteration complete: Current best fit is  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,0)[12]+c 21562.904816
# ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,1)[12]+c 21710.467789
# ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[12]   21469.103988
# Search iteration complete: Current best fit is  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
# ...
# ...
# ...
```

Comment: One option would be to use `capture <- capture.output(fcst <- df |> model(arima = ARIMA(Count, trace = TRUE)))` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118977/capture-the-printed-output-from-a-function-but-still-return-its-value-in-r.

But then you would have to parse through the text output.

Comment: Why not just write it to a `file` with `capture.output` i.e. `capture.output(fcst <- df |> model(arima = ARIMA(Count, trace = TRUE)), file = file.path(getwd(),  'arimaout.text'))` and then go over the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options to read the output

1. Write the output of `capture.output` to a `file`

```
capture.output(fcst <- df |>
        model(arima = ARIMA(Count, trace = TRUE)), 
       file = file.path(getwd(),  'arimaout.text'))
```

2. May also use a package (`logger`) to write it to a log file

```
library(logger)
log_formatter(formatter_glue)
 t <- tempfile()
 log_appender(appender_file(t))
 log_info('{capture.output(fcst <- df |> model(arima = ARIMA(Count, trace = TRUE)))}') 
 log_appender()
```

-read the log file

```
readLines(t) |> 
     head()
[1] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] Model specification\t\tSelection metric"                       
[2] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,0,1)[12]+c\tInf"                                
[3] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[12]+c\t21811.280078"                       
[4] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[12]+c\t21524.227259"                       
[5] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[12]+c\t21470.955343"                       
[6] "INFO [2021-12-04 12:20:58] Search iteration complete: Current best fit is  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 "
```

`unlink` if temporary file

```
unlink(t)
```