# Doornik & Hansen normality test using R (normality.test2)

Tags: r

I am testing for normality using the (adjusted) Doornik-Hansen test in R: [`normwhn.test::normality.test2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/normwhn.test/versions/1.0/topics/normality.test2). The test works fine, but I would like to extract specific elements from the test, i.e. the test statistic (Ep) and the significance of the test statistic (Sig.Ep). I have the following line of code defining a metrix/vector and then test for normality:

```
m_1 <- matrix(data[,2], nrow = nrow(data), ncol = 1)
normality.test2(m_1)
```

Can any of you explain to me how i extract a certain element? I have tried to use brackets, e.g. `normality.test2(m_1)[1]` but without succes.

Comment: Perhaps add the library and reproducible data. I tested it, seems your best bet is to `capture.output(normality.test2(m_1))`

Comment: Try storing the return value in a variable first and check the class. It is probably a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of `normwhn.test::normality.test2` 
(just evaluate it without parentheses), you'll see that all the info you 
want is just printed to the screen, not part of the return value. For example these are the last few lines:

```
  ...
  dof <- 2 * nvars
  sig.Ep <- 1 - pchisq(Ep, dof)
  print("H0: data are normally distributed")
  print("Ep")
  print(Ep)
  print("dof")
  print(dof)
  print("sig.Ep")
  print(sig.Ep)
}
```

So the two best options would be:

1. just re-write the function, returning a list of all the things you want
   instead of printing them; or
2. wrap the call to `normality.test2` in `capture.output()` to return everything that was printed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358435/in-r-is-it-possible-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-variable) for reference).

Option 2. might take less effort up front, but the results will get returned as a character vector (one element for each line printed to the console), and you'll have to parse that to get what you want.

An example of strategy 2.:

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2)
m_1 <- matrix(data[,2], nrow = nrow(data), ncol = 1)
test_result_output <- capture.output(normwhn.test::normality.test2(m_1))
```

You can then start parsing the output with e.g.:

```
gsub("\"|\\[,*1,*\\]", "", test_result_output)

## ...
## ...
## [32] " Ep"                                    
## [33] "         "                              
## [34] " 1.512684"                              
## [35] " dof"                                   
## [36] " 2"                                     
## [37] " sig.Ep"                                
## [38] "          "                             
## [39] " 0.4693803"
```

(fwiw, if I were you, I would just grab the code of the function and rewrite it so that it returns what you want. Much easier in the long run. Maybe even consider sending the authors a message, and asking if they'd consider introducing a parameter like `output_in_return_value`.)